# Why is the water pressure in my condo pulsing?

Tags: water, pressure

In the condo where I live cold water pulsates (swiftly drops) with a period of 10 seconds (so when showering the temperature increases by the same pattern). What could be the cause?

Comment: Who else is using water when you shower? Has this been going on from day one or is this a recent change?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you don't have a pressure-balance control valve in your shower.
When someone flushes a toilet the cold pressure drops and the hot water gets hotter.

This is exactly why pressure-balance controls have been mandated in most localities.

More info is needed for instructions on how to change to a PB control.
It usually involves opening a wall.

Or call a plumber to get a quote on replacement.

Comment: The 10 seconds period is too regular to be explained like that.